# Show this delta function equalitty.

Tags: calculus

Show that $\delta(f(x)) = \sum_{i} \frac{(\delta(x-x_{i}))}{|f'(x_{i})|}$

' is first derivative.

xi are roots of the f(x) function

Now i thought that would be a good idea do compare their influence in the integral of any other function, g(x), but i noticed that:

$\int g(x)\delta(f(x))dx = \sum g(x_{i})$

While

$\int (g(x)\sum_{i} \frac{(\delta(x-x_{i}))}{|f'(x_{i})|})dx = \frac{\sum g(x_{i})}{|f'(x_{i})|}$

This is a little strange, i can't see my error (observe that f'(xi) is not variable, it is in fact a lot of constant)

Comment: Hint: What can you say about $\int g(x)\delta(a\cdot x) \text{d} x$?

Comment: @Toffomat oh... of course, i forget it. that's enough, thank you